# Exec of 'dbupgrade' returned non-zero status of '0x1' error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

Exec of 'dbupgrade' returned non-zero status of '0x1' error. This error appears right after trying to start the Oracle Database. This stops the FileNet software from starting. After many different attempts at a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this page https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-users-are-required-rdb-upgrade-ibm-filenet-image-services

Article about FileNet Image Services but symptoms are the same, "dbupgrade" fails. It is related to removed DB users.